# Perl system command split ignoring html

Tags: perl

```
my $hosts = qx{cat /home/user/hostlist};
my @hostfield = split(/\\n/, $hosts);
print "$_<br />\n" foreach (@hostfield);
```

The output is giving me the list of hosts but not inserting br statements, this will be very important once I start inserting the other commands for execution instead of printing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Try printing @hostfield after assigning to it. Does it contain what you think it does? Data::Dumper can be useful when checking.

Comment: A simpler way to do it is `my @hostfield = qx{cat ...}`. Even simpler `print ... for qx(cat ...)` and even simpler still is `perl -nle'print "$_<br />"' /home/user/hostlist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are splitting on a literal backslash followed by an n (`\n`), because of your double backslash (`\\`).

All you should have to change is remove the extra `\` in your split().

Comment: I thought I tried it both ways but when I did I had put in a ( \r ) as well. I feel silly, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Shelling out to `cat` just to read a file is wasteful.

Instead you could write this

```
our @ARGV = ('/home/user/hostlist');
print s|$|<br/>|r while <>;
```